# how to translate `if b < a` condition to match pattern?

Tags: ocaml

Like the `if .. then` in code

```
# let rec range2 a b accum =
  if b < a then accum
  else range2 a (b - 1) (b :: accum);;
```

how to write this `b < a` as a pattern in `match .. with` ? sth like

```
let rec range2 a b accum = match .. with 
  | ..
```

Comment: OCaml patterns are good at matching structures where part is fixed and part can be anything. They aren't good at comparing integers. So I would wonder why you want to do this. If you absolutelly must use `match` you could perhaps match `b < a` against `true` and `false`.

Comment: thanks Jeffrey for the comment, for learning purpose :)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I commonly need to distinguish cases based on a mix of structural and arithmetic (or string) patterns. Also, I’m so visually accustomed to `match` for case distinction when there are more than 2 alternatives, that I might use it willingly even with `when` guards only. I find its structure clearer than nested `if then else` (for which you might get nesting wrong, BTW; it’s easy to write `if … then … ; if … then …` rather than `if … then … else if … then …`).

Comment: For what it's worth, I think `if/then/else` is much clearer than using `when` if there's no actual pattern being matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to structurally pattern match anything, then `match` likely doesn't make sense. If/else exists for reason, after all.

However, you may want to learn about conditional guards on patterns.  Let's say I wanted to convert an int to a type with constructors `Zero`, `Even` and `Odd`.

```
let convert =
  function
  | 0 -> Zero
  | n when n % 2 = 0 -> Even
  | _ -> Odd
```

As compared to:

```
let convert n =
  if n = 0 then Zero
  else if n % 2 = 0 then Even
  else Odd
```

Or:

```
let convert =
  function
  | 0 -> Zero
  | n -> if n % 2 = 0 then Even else Odd
```

Comment: Also `match n % 2 with | 0 -> if n = 0 then Zero else Even | _ -> Odd`. Although I shudder at the thought that 0 is treated as non-even.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the following use of pattern-matching to replace if-else (matching on `()` with guards)

```ml
match () with
| _ when b < a -> accum
| _ -> range2 a (b - 1) (b :: accum)
```

But it is very conflictual whether this is ok to write, or very bad style. Arguments against are that this approach is convoluted / doesn’t use the structual pattern aspect of structural pattern matching. Arguments for are that the `match` syntax is generally much more readable than the `if`-`else` syntax (especially if nesting is involved).

Comment: I only use that syntax when there are more than 2 cases or some structure matching is done as well. `if then else` better describes what is going on there I feel.